# Saving a file with a variable of datatype 'Data" in Swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, swift5, data-persistence

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to write a function in Swift to download a JSON and parse it.
However, the JSON is very complicated and I have a daily limit on number of requests of data from the server.

Is there a way to download the data and save it to a file as 'data' so I can run all tests on this data in the file and not have to get it from the server everytime? Once I'm ready, I can start getting data from the server again.

Basically I could initialize a data variable with the contents of the file so I can use it on my tests.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can download the data and add it to your project. Then you can load it from your application bundle.

Answer (score 2):

1. Determine where you want to store it and what it should be named. For example, for files that can be re-retrieved from the network, we’d use the `cachesDirectory`:

   ```
   let folder = try! FileManager.default
       .url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
       .appendingPathComponent("downloads")
   ```

   Or, you can use the `applicationSupportDirectory` (if re-retrieving it is impractical) or `.documentsDirectory` (if you want to potentially expose the file to the end user). But the idea is the same.
2. Create that folder if you haven’t already:

   ```
   try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: folder, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
   ```
3. Create URL for the file within that folder:

   ```
   let fileURL = folder.appendingPathComponent("sample.json")
   ```
4. Save that `Data` to that fileURL:

   ```
   do {
       try data.write(to: fileURL)
   } catch {
       print(error)
   }
   ```

Comment: I get the following error on the line with the data.write - Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'Target' -- I was getting that error earlier, but I couldn't figure out why it is happening.

Comment: Thank you, I actually got it. I had the wrong type being passed into the function.